# How do I install TestNG in Eclipse Mars 2?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin, testng

I have tried everything to install TestNG but it just can not be found by Eclipse. Please help me with it.

Comment: Have you added the Jars to your classpath or the dependencies to your POM?

Comment: hi plz go to the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589607/how-to-use-testng-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

open eclipse > Help >Eclipse Marketplace(click here).

after opening the marketplace window,than in find, write testng and click on go button.

Testng for eclipse will be shown. Than just click on install button to install it.

Comment: @Akash Dugam,  have u installed it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the documentation: http://testng.org/doc/download.html